# OrientDB: Gremlin Count query extremely slow

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

I'm trying to find count (for pagination) in OrientDB 2.2 using gremlin and when my class has a lot of vertices (1 million), this query just dies (record count for startsWith 'smi' filter is about 6000). I already have a fulltext (sbtree) created on last_name field.

```
g.getVerticesOfClass('person')._().filter{it.getProperty("last_name").startsWith("smi")}.count()
```

How can I write this better so count comes back in reasonable time. I haven't added sort yet, because its giving me outOfMemory.

Answer (score 2):

You may have more luck with something that uses the Gremlin `.has()` step rather than the native Groovy `.filter()` method with a lambda. The following could be faster:

```
g.getVerticesOfClass('person')._().has('last_name').startsWith('smi').count()
```

If you're using https://github.com/mpollmeier/orientdb-gremlin, I don't think the query optimizer can yet use indexes for queries with `startsWith()` predicates.

Comment: thanks, but I think there's an error in script. has would return a pipe and  startsWith is not working right after that

Comment: You're right and I didn't pay attention, sorry :). Your best bet would be to open an issue here: https://github.com/mpollmeier/orientdb-gremlin You might also want to edit your first query and filter for elements with the `last_name` property first, ie. `g.getVerticesOfClass('person')._().has("last_name").filter{it.getProperty("last_name").startsWith("smi")}.count()`. The more Gremlin steps you use, the more optimizers can kick in. Native Groovy functions can't.